# How to use the read/writeable local XML settings?

Tags: c#, xml, .net-4.0, settings, rapid-prototyping

I found something similar to what I need here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/PropertiesSettings.aspx
But it does not quite do it for me. The user settings are stored in some far away location such as `C:\documents and settings\[username]\local settings\application data\[your application]`, but I do not have access to these folders and I cannot copy the settings file from one computer to another, or to delete the file altogether. Also, it would be super-convenient to have the settings xml file right next to the app, and to copy/ship both. This is used for demo-ware (which is a legitimate type of coding task) and will be used by non-technical people in the field. I need to make this quickly, so I need to reuse some existing library and not write my own. I need to make it easy to use and be portable. The last thing I want is to get a call at midnight that says that settings do not persist when edited through the settings dialog that I will have built.

So, user settings are stored god knows where, and application settings are read-only (no go). Is there anything else that I can do? I think app.config file has multiple purposes and I think I once saw it being used the way I want, I just cannot find the link.

Let me know if something is not clear.

Comment: There's basically two reasons why settings aren't usually stored next to the excutable: 1. users often don't have write access to the executable's folder (e.g. if it's in Program Files); 2. a computer can have more than one user, each of whom would want his own settings. You'd better have a very good reason if you want to go against established convention on this (and know that sysadmins everywhere will hate you if you do).

Comment: @Sven, I do have reason(s) which I already listed. In practice I never encountered an exe to which I had no access, but user settings - I cannot get to that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could create a class that holds your settings and then XML-serialize it:

```
public class Settings
{
    public string Setting1 { get; set; }
    public int Setting2 { get; set; }
}

static void SaveSettings(Settings settings)
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
    using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(SettingsFilePath))
    {
        serializer.Serialize(stream, settings);
    }
}

static Settings LoadSettings()
{
    if (!File.Exists(SettingsFilePath))
        return new Settings();

    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings));
    using (var stream = File.OpenRead(SettingsFilePath))
    {
        return (Settings)serializer.Deserialize(stream);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, could you add a bit more details?

Comment: Thanks! Would wrapping `var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Settings))` inside `using` be useless?

Comment: @Hamish, that wouldn't be useless, that would be invalid and the code wouldn't even compile, because `XmlSerializer` doesn't implement `IDisposable`.