# Where should I put my connection strings for my class library and how do I access them?

Tags: c#, connection-string

I have a solution with 4/5 projects.

I currently have the connection string for my domain project hardcoded in a c# file.

I'd like to put this in a web.config or something. From what I've been reading here and elsewhere I should store these connection strings in the web config of the calling application?

If so how do I access it?

When I do something like this in my class library:

```
ConnectionStringSettingsCollection connectionStrings =
    connectionStringsSection.ConnectionStrings;
```

The type or namespace could not be found, am I missing a reference or something?

Comment: For some odd reason (Microsoft, you know) the required assembly is not referenced by default. You have to manually add reference to `System.Configuration` assembly to each project that need to use it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an existing schema in the `config` schema for connection strings.

This goes under the `<configuration>` element:

```
<connectionStrings>
  <add name="example" connectionString="..."/>
</connectionStrings>
```

In your code, you should use [`ConfigurationManager`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) to access them. In order to have the reference to it you need to add a `using System.Configuration;` namespace to your file and the `System.Configuration.dll` assembly reference to your project (if not already there).

```
string conn = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["example"];
```

Comment: ConfigurationManager is a good choice, and 2 other choices that i remember now : Registry and binary file (using binary formatter), check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9375112/storing-application-settings-in-project-folder-rather-than-appdata/9375425#9375425

Comment: @AmenAyach - Since the OP specifically asked about `web.config`, registry and binary files are not really suitable.

Comment: @iKode - Have you added a reference to `System.Configuration.dll` to your project?

Comment: @Oded that was it, I thought I had already included it because I had a 'using System.Configuration' in my file. Still getting used to Visual studio / asp.net etc Thanks for your help.

Comment: @iKode - No problem. Having a namespace mentioned in a file does not mean it has been referenced, as you have now learnt...

Comment: I cant find by COnfiguration Element

Answer (score 6):

You need to add a reference to [System.Configuration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.aspx) in your main project.

then you can access connection string like this...

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnectionString"].ConnectionString;//<- last bit for a string version of the full connection string
```

[ConfigurationManager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.configuration.configurationmanager.aspx) will also let you access a number of other useful properties from your web.config file (this will also work for app.config files)

Answer (score 4):

Define with your main application and accessin class lib

ConnectionStrings : Add using System.Configuration;
add ref : System.Configuration;

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["key"]
```

alternetive

```
System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["key"])
```

Comment: this is only if your connection string is in "AppSettings", it should really be in the "ConnectionStrings" tag for web.config files

Comment: Why not use the built in `ConnectionStrings` section exposed by `ConfigurationManager`? Using `AppSettings` for connection strings has been discouraged since .NET 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

use this inside your code.

```
String sqlDbConn = 
        ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ToString();
```

the name should also defind in your web config;

```
<connectionStrings>
 <add name="ApplicationServices"
       connectionString="You database information"
      />

 </connectionStrings>
```

and also add using System.Configuration; namespace

Comment: The `ToString()` call is redundant.